# How to use firebase-admin in express.js Vue.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, nuxt.js, firebase-admin

I just want to set custom claims in the user account. I'm using express.js as a backend and Vue.js as a frontend. I initialize the app with name, but still, it's showing the error ("The default firebase app does not exist").

**This is my code:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

var firebaseadmin = require('firebase-admin')
var serviceAccount = require('./adminconfig.json')
firebaseadmin.initializeApp({
        credential: firebaseadmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    },
    'appname'
)

app.post('/test', async(req, res) => {
         await firebaseadmin
             .auth()
              .setCustomUserClaims(req.body.uid, req.body.role)
             .then((res) => {
                 console.log('then', res)
                 res.send(req.body)
             })
             .catch((error) => {
                 console.log('error', error)
             })
    res.send('hello')
})

    enter code here

module.exports = { path: '/api', handler: app }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just call admin.initializeApp() at the global scope of your code.

Don't pass any parameters to accept the default service account, which should have permission to read and write your Cloud Firestore database.

Comment: hi,  First Arachne I added the code which i used